# Brainteaser - coin

Tags: probability

The brainteaser: Imagine you have a special dollar. You can play a game with me. I'll toss a coin and if you call it right, you have two dollars; if not, you take home only one dollar. You can keep playing if you call correctly, doubling your money each time How much would you pay for the special dollar?

I know that the answer to this question is that the expected payoff is infinite and the amount you are willing to pay depends on your risk aversion. But how would we express the expected payoff in round 1, round 2 and round 3 and then round n?

Is the following correct:
Round 1: 0.5*(2)+0.5*(1)=1.5
Round 2: Since we must flip right the first toss in order to flip it again, we get 2 + 1/4*(0.5*(4)+0.5*(1))
Round 3: 2 + 4 + 1/16*(0.5*(8)+0.5*(1))
Round n:

Comment: Can't critique definitively, because you didn't use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to display your math.